# Edit associated model from view of another model (CakePHP 3)

Tags: cakephp, view, cakephp-3.0, edit

I am still fairly new to CakePHP, though I like to think I have some basic understanding.

I have made a basic blog, based on an 'articles' table and `bake all`, piece of cake so far ;D. Now I've added a 'comments' table. 'articles' hasMany 'comments' and 'comments' belongsTo 'articles'. I again `baked all` for both tables and edited the 'view' action in ArticlesController.php and Articles/view.ctp to display all the comments of an article. No issues yet.

Now I'd like to be able to add a comment on the 'view' page of an article, much like you can comment on this forum. So I've added an `Html->Form` to view.ctp and copied some parts from the comment's add() to the article's view(). Article's view action:

```
public function view($id = null) {

$article = $this->Articles->get($id, [
    'contain' => ['Comments']
]);

// Part from the add-action from Comments
$comment = $this->Comments->newEntity();
if ($this->request->is('post')) {
    $comment = $this->Comments->patchEntity($comment, $this->request->data);
    if ($this->Comments->save($comment)) {
        $this->Flash->success(__('The comment has been saved.'));
        return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
    } else {


      $this->Flash->error(__('The comment could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
    }

    // Set the selected article
    $this->set('article', $article);
    $this->set('_serialize', ['article']);
}
```

A part from Articles/view.ctp :

```
<?php foreach ($article->comments as $comment) : ?>

    <h5><?= $comment->author ?></h5>

    <p><?= $comment->body ?></p>

<?php endforeach; ?>


<b>Add comment</b>

<?= $this->Form->create($comment) ?>
<?php
echo $this->Form->input('comment.author');
echo $this->Form->input('comment.body');
?>
<?= $this->Form->button(__('Submit Comment')) ?>
<?= $this->Form->end() ?>
```

But this gives me a fatal error, :

> Error: Call to a member function newEntity() on boolean  File
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\blog_simple\src\Controller\ArticlesController.php 
>   Line: 45

Any suggestions on how to accomplish what I'm looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Error: Call to a member function newEntity() on boolean  File
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\blog_simple\src\Controller\ArticlesController.php 
>   Line: 45

Because you are in `Articles` Controller and you are trying `Comments` related functions (without Loading Model).

You have two option.

1. If you have correct relationship set up, then append `Articles` to calls like,

   ```
   $comment = $this->Comments->newEntity();
   ```

   to

   ```
   $comment = $this->Articles->Comments->newEntity();
   ```

Similarly do for all the comments `PatchEntity` and `Save` function.

2. Add

   `$this->loadModel('Comments');`

   before calling `Comments` related functions. No need to append `Articles` like mentioned in previous point. Because, we are loading model.

Try which one you prefer. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Replacing "Comments->" by "Articles->Comments" in the action has removed the error, but no comments are added yet. EDIT: I see my own flash error, so `save($comment)` does not succeed.

Comment: For not only newEntity(), you have to add it for below calls too.

Comment: I read the answer. I replaced it everywhere in the action. And there is no error. It just does not save it. Is there any way of getting some information from the `->save()` function?

Comment: Figured it out! The form in the view still had `comment.author` etc. in stead of just `author` etc. Removing "comment." fixed it. Thanks again!